# which is the best iPhone and Android Simulator for Kubuntu Linux?

Tags: mobile

Which is the best iPhone and Android Simulator for Kubuntu Linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Iphone simulator for Linux. For Android you should use the simulator included in [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).